# How do I have libcurl3 and php-curl for version 7.2 installed at the same time?

Tags: php, libcurl, php-curl, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2

I do..
sudo apt-get install php-curl
and libcurl3 is uninstalled
I do ..
 
sudo apt-get install libcurl3
and php-curl is uninstalled